# How to calculate the average quadratic velocity of carbon dioxide from given data?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

I am working on this question, and I am unsure of how to proceed. The question is:

> There is $31.7~\mathrm{g}$ of $\ce{CO2 (g)}$ in a container. The partial pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ is $2.62~\mathrm{atm}$ and the volume of the container is $26.8~\mathrm{L}$. What is the average quadratic velocity ($\mathrm{m/s}$) of the $\ce{CO2}$ in the container?

I think that the formula I should use is this one: $V = \sqrt{3RT/M}$, but I am unsure on how to find the temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Ideal Gas Law: $PV=nRT \to T = \frac{PV}{nR}$.  From the mass you can find the number of moles, $n$. $P$ and $V$ are given, and $R$ is the universal gas constant.

Even better you could rearrange the equation to $RT = \frac{PV}{n}$, substitue the value for $RT$ and do less arithmatic.